# Wix How to insert a custom dialog

Tags: wix

I have Wix configured to use WixUI_Minimal and have a number of dialogs restricted.

I also created a custom Dialog to gather some user input.
Now i am unsure how to insert the custom Dialog and at the correct sequence.

I would like to insert custom Dialog after the WelcomeDlg

How do i do this?

here is my UI.

```
<UI Id="WixUI_Minimal">
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Minimal" />

  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

   <!--This is the welcome dialog you specified-->
  <DialogRef Id="WelcomeDlg" />

   <!--Hook the new welcome dialog to the next one in the stack-->
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PrepareDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
</UI>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

need this in my customdlg

Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomDlg">1

and removed the declaration from the above